# Identify Amadeus API that uses "cartID"

Tags: rest

I am trying to find if a field we are using, `cartID`, has a checksum, for some defensive code that I need to add to our system.

There are quite a few implementations I can find in google that make me feel that `cartID` is a standard field, EG:
`GET https://proxy.digitalforairlines.com/v2/purchase/orders?cartId=002R8JC9UMNJK0G8`
(Our implementation looks exactly the same)

Response can look something like this:

```
  "data": {
    "id": "ABCD1234WXYZ5678",
    "travelers": [
      {
        "passengerTypeCode": "ADT",
        "id": "BBB-1-AAA",
        "names": [
          {
            "firstName": "Name",
            "lastName": "Here",
            "nameType": "universal"
          }
        ]
      },
```

However, I can't see any reference to `cartID` code in the Amadeus API docs.

Assuming my first step is to find what is the API that takes `cartId` ("Flight Create Orders"?), does any of the above request/response format look familiar enough for someone to refer me to the correct API (dare I ask for a link to the docs)?